# 2 elementary counting problems (combinatorics)

Tags: combinatorics

I'm reading Lady Luck by Warren Weaver. My answers for two of the problems in chapter 4 don't match the given answers.

> 1. How many three-letter words, each to contain one of the five regular vowels, can be made from an alphabet of $26$ letters, permitting repeititions?

Given answer:$ 5\cdot 26\cdot 25 + 26\cdot 5\cdot 26 + 26\cdot 26\cdot 5$

My answer: $5\cdot 21 \cdot 21+ 21\cdot 5 \cdot 21 + 21\cdot 21 \cdot 5$

If the vowel is in position $1$, there are $5$ choices. For each of those choices, there are $21$ consonant choices $(26-5=21)$ for the second position and $21$ consonant choices for the third position. Same reasoning and number for words with the vowel in the second position and third position.

Since repetition of consonants is allowed, the $25$ in the first factor of the book's given answer makes no sense to me. The factors of $26$ in the book-answer's second and third terms also seem wrong to me since the problem states each word contains only one vowel.

> 2. How many types of banana splits can Howard Johnson's make with any two of twenty-eight sorts of ice cream and anyone of ten syrup flavors?

Given answer: $7560$

My answer: $\binom{28}{2}\cdot 10 = \frac{(28)(27)}{2}\cdot 10 = 3780. $

There are $28$ ways to choose first ice cream flavor. for each of those ways, there are $27$ ways to choose the second flavor.

However, this includes duplicates like chocolate vanilla and vanilla chocolate so have to divide by number of ways to arrange $2$. So that part is $\binom{28}{2}.$ For each of those $28$ choose $2$ ice cream combinations, there are $10$ syrup flavors to choose from. So $\binom{28}{2} \cdot 10 = 3780.$ I think the book-answer over-counts by a factor of $2.$

Can someone explain why my reasoning is incorrect? Or do I have the correct answers and the book-given answers are wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When they say the words can be made with repetitions, you can also repeat the vowels. *However* the book's answer is *also* wrong.

Consider that `words with at least one vowel = all words - words with no vowels`

and `words with no vowels` = $21^3$

Thus the number of words you want is $26^3 - 21^3 = 8315$.

The book over-counts some words: the book enforces a position to be a vowel and then admits repetitions on the other positions, which is fine, but then over-counts the number of words that have 2 or more vowels.

For your second question, it surely has to do with the fact that a chocolate-vanilla banana split is not the same as a vanilla-chocolate one. Maybe they put the ice-cream on top of each other and then the syrup is poured only on top of one? Don't know, never really seen a banana split.